# Some of greater elements after merge step are not on the right from the pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I've written the quicksort algorithm that gives correct answer in the most examples(probably not all).

The code at the bottom of the post gives the output:

```
7 3 5 8 3 1 
pivot: 5
i = 0 j = 5 swaps 7 with 1
1 3 5 8 3 7 
i = 2 j = 4 swaps 5 with 3
1 3 3 8 5 7 //BUT the pivot was 5 why there is 5 on the right from 8?
pivot: 3
i = 1 j = 2 swaps 3 with 3
1 3 3 8 5 7 
pivot: 1
i = 0 j = 0 swaps 1 with 1
1 3 3 8 5 7 
pivot: 3
i = 2 j = 2 swaps 3 with 3
1 3 3 8 5 7 
pivot: 5
i = 3 j = 4 swaps 8 with 5
1 3 3 5 8 7 
pivot: 8
i = 4 j = 5 swaps 8 with 7
1 3 3 5 7 8 //FINALLY CORRECT RESULT
```

Which in the end is the right result, but the anomaly occures in the beginning of the output. After the first merge we have `1 3 3 8 5 7` but the pivot was 5. Altough in the end the array is sort correctly. I couldn't find array that would make algorithm fail.

Where did I make mistake in my code?

```
public class Quicksort {

    public static void partition(int[] t, int i, int j) {
        if (i >= j) {
            return;
        }
        int start = i, end = j;
        int pivot = t[(i + j) / 2]; // select the pivot as the middle value
        System.out.println("pivot: " + pivot);
        int temp;
        while (i < j) {
            while (t[i] < pivot) { // looking for value greater or equal to the  pivot
                i++;
            }
            while (t[j] > pivot) { // looking for value lower or equal to the  pivot
                j--;
            }
            System.out.println("i = " + i + " j = " + j + " swaps " + t[i] + " with " + t[j]);
            if (i <= j) {
                temp = t[i]; // swap
                t[i] = t[j];
                t[j] = temp;
                i++; // move to the next element
                j--; // move to the prev element
            }
            display(t);
        }
        partition(t, start, j); // partition for the left part of the array
        partition(t, i, end); // partiion for the right part of the array
    }

    public static void display(int[] t) {
        for (int el : t)
            System.out.print(el + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] t = { 7, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1 };
        display(t);
        partition(t, 0, t.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting algorithm is essentially correct.

I believe we can prove that by showing that your partition step will result in:

`all elements in the left part <= pivot`

and

`all elements if the right part >= pivot`.

Then it is enough to sort individually. Confirm for small arrays, and you have an induction proof.

To get a "proper" partition like `[< pivot, = pivot, > pivot]` you need to make sure your invariants are properly maintained.

You might need three pointers, instead of the two you are using. See [Dutch National Flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

btw, you should call your recursive method `sort` and not partition. The while loop is the partition step.